# Search nearby restaurants using Zomato API

Tags: java, android, api

I am trying to search nearby restaurants using zomato API and showing it into my app but I am getting null values.
[Zomato API](https://developers.zomato.com/documentation?lang=hi#!/common/geocode)

```
I am using location details based on coordinates
```

> https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode?lat=21.046900&lon=75.782070

When I debug the app I'm getting a null response.

It's my first time to use API in my android app, I'm using a retrofit. My aim to get a list of nearby restaurants using my current location and then show it into my app.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.zomatoapi;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ZomatoApi.baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ZomatoApi zomatoApi = retrofit.create(ZomatoApi.class);

    Call<CurrentCity> listCall = zomatoApi.getCurrentCities();

    listCall.enqueue(new Callback<CurrentCity>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CurrentCity> call, Response<CurrentCity> response) {

            CurrentCity currentCity = response.body();

            List<Object> objects = currentCity.getNearbyRestaurants();

            for (Object object : objects)
            {
                Log.i("Heyy",object.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CurrentCity> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

**ZomatoApi.zava**

```
package com.example.zomatoapi;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;

public interface ZomatoApi {
String baseUrl = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/";

@Headers("user-key: 1d63821dbb228ee5d09e8c8f7cfe10c3")
@GET("/api/v2.1/geocode?lat=21.046900&lon=75.782070")
 Call<CurrentCity> getCurrentCities();
}
```

*Please help and sorry for my bad writing skills*

Answer (score 0):

You are appending `"api/v2.1/"` with base url as well as with the individual request in the interface. Remove `"/api/v2.1/"` from interface @GET request.